# How to read a csv that contains commas in multiple columns where delimiter is already a comma in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 27 fields in line 2, saw 29
```

The above is the error I get.

Example Data:

```
DateID,Date,Day,FY
20030106,2003-02-06,Mon Jan 06, 2003,FY 2003
20030106,2003-02-06,Mon Jan 06, 2003,FY 2003
20030106,2003-03-06,Mon Jan 06, 2003,FY 2003
```

Code I tried was
pd.read_csv()

Comment: If the field contains a literal comma, it needs to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Otherwise, how is the CSV parser supposed ot know which commas are delimiters and which are data?

Comment: ``pd.read_csv(sep=',')``? this should fail though since you have a comma between the dates. You might have some luck using a regex

Comment: Yes, @sammywemmy It fails if I use that with the parse error I mentioned. Not really sure how to fix that using a regex

Comment: You basically tell in the header (first line) that you have 4 fields, but you have 5. You can choose to see the entire line as ONE field, and process using regular expression / substring, depending on your data being fixed/variable length.

Comment: @MyICQ Can you point me to an example link where something like that is done?

Comment: I think you'll need to parse the csv yourself using `open() as f` and `f.read().split('\n')`, then write your own regex to parse into list and then convert to df with `pd.DataFrame`